How to filter users in directory by company name with Microsoft Graph Java SDK?
I'm working with Microsoft Graph API to get users from my organisation. Here's what I have so far that fetches all users:
TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(

Collections.singletonList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
                clientSecretCredential
        );

GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient
        .builder()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .buildClient();

List<User> allUsers = new LinkedList<>();
var usersPage = graphClient.users()
        .buildRequest()
        .get();

while (usersPage != null) {
    usersPage.getCurrentPage().forEach(allUsers::add);
    usersPage = usersPage.getNextPage() != null ?
usersPage.getNextPage().buildRequest().get() : null;
}

allUsers.forEach(user ->
        System.out.println("User: " + user.displayName + " | ID: " + user.id)
);

Now, I need to filter these users to retrieve only those associated with my company name, like "XiaoZCorp" with filter like this:
var usersPage = graphClient.users()
        .buildRequest()
        .filter("companyName eq 'XiaoZCorp'") // This line throws an error
        .get();

However, I’m getting this error:
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method filter(java.lang.String)
  location: class com.microsoft.graph.requests.UserCollectionRequestBuilder

How can I properly filter users by company name using Microsoft Graph API in Java SDK?

Initially, I registered one application and granted User.Read.All permission of Application type as below:

I have below users in Azure Portal with company name 'MSFT' in my case:

To get these user details using Microsoft Graph Java SDK, you can make use of below sample code:
package org.example;

import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.UserCollectionPage;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.UserCollectionRequestBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.UserCollectionRequest;
import com.microsoft.graph.options.QueryOption;

import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String clientId = "appId";
        String clientSecret = "secret";
        String tenantId = "tenantId";

        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .build();

        TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
                Collections.singletonList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
                clientSecretCredential
        );

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .buildClient();

        UserCollectionRequestBuilder requestBuilder = graphClient.users();

        UserCollectionRequest request = requestBuilder
                .buildRequest()
                .select("companyName,id,displayName")
                .filter("companyName eq 'MSFT'");

        // Add ConsistencyLevel header
        request.addHeader("ConsistencyLevel", "Eventual");

        // Add $count query parameter
        request.addQueryOption(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));

        UserCollectionPage result = request.get();

        // Print out the filtered users
        result.getCurrentPage().forEach(user ->
                System.out.println("User: " + user.displayName + " | ID: " + user.id)
        );
    }
}

Response:

Make sure to add ConsistencyLevel : eventual and $count:true headers as filtering with company name requires advanced query capability.
Reference:
Use the $filter query parameter to filter a collection of objects - Microsoft Graph
